# Mathematical induction: Can I assume $P(k-x)$ holds true?

Tags: logic, induction

In mathematical induction we assume $P(k)$ holds for some unspecified value $k$ and try to prove $P(k+1)$. When doing so can we assume that $P(k-x)$ also holds, given that $k-x >$ base case and $x\in\Zeta$?

On one hand this appears valid as $P(k-x)$ is true IFF $P(k)$ is true. However I am worried about the "for some unspecified value $k$" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is sometimes called [complete (strong) induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Complete_(strong)_induction) which in itself is a special case of [wellfounded induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-founded_relation#Induction_and_recursion).

The latter is a theorem (rather a scheme of theorems) in the theory $\mathrm{ZF}$.